# Strange extra characters in rendered html on IE 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, mono, apache2, excanvas

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that I want to render some custom HTML 5 canvasses in. I am getting a strange issue with the server serving up extra characters that are not in the source code.

In order to use an HTML 5 canvas in IE 8 you have to add the following tag in the html head:

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="../../Scripts/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

For some reason this is served up as:

```
<!--[if IE]>IE]><script src="../../Scripts/excanvas.js"></scr<![endif]-->
```

Of course the duff markup causes the excanvas script to not be loaded by IE. I can't understand why the line gets garbled. I have the following doctype which is documented at http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I'm not familiar with using HTML 5 or the new doctype so I'm suspicious of it. I'm also hosting on Apache with Mono so maybe that's what's garbling the line.

The page in question is at: http://openancestry.org/FamilyTree/Simpsons

Anyone seen this before or know why I cant use the "if IE" syntax?

UPDATE:
Well I'm pretty sure it's either Mono or Apache thats garbling the HTML so I've used the workaround below which adds a compatibility meta tag for IE8 and includes excanvas for any IE that predates IE9.
I'd still appreciate any answers on why the HTML gets garbled.

```
<% if (Request.Browser.Browser.Contains("IE") && float.Parse(Request.Browser.Version) < 9) { %>
<% if (float.Parse(Request.Browser.Version) > 7) { %>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<% } %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/excanvas.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Very odd. Off-topic: [it looks like IE 9 is going to support the `<canvas>` tag](http://www.windows7news.com/2010/06/24/microsoft-confirms-features-for-ie9-canvas-and-video-tags/), so you probably want your conditional comment to select IE 8 and earlier. This should work (once the server stops chewing it up): `<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="../../Scripts/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Comment: Also, please refer to the official documentation http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/ and never use W3schools.

Comment: @grenade, I used the solution you provided in the update to your question, thanks for that.

Just wanted to note that I was having the same problem in the following version of Mono for Apache, on Yosemite:
Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0 (4 years since the question was first asked!)

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, I want to point out that you are missing `type="text/javascript"` in your example.

It is possible that the ASP.NET parser in Mono is mangling your comment. What version of Mono are you using (and what platform I suppose).

I just tried this on Mono 2.10 on Mac and did not have this problem.

Comment: I think `type="text/javascript"` is discouraged in HTML 5.

Comment: @Xavier - Thanks. I did not even know it was optional. The reason I mentioned it is that I thought it could confuse ASP.NET since you can use the script tag to have C# or VB.NET code as well.